# Silverlight 4 - How to access data store elements from c# class?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, datastore

I am new here and to Silverlight so please bear with me even if this is a simple question, although searching for answers didn't present me anything.

I have created my simple project in which I have a data store with properties that are values (numbers). I know that in Expression Blend I can use the behavior `SetDataStoreValueAction` to increment but I need to decrement these values. So I need to access the data store property I want from the C# class from the function that is going to receive the value to decrement. I have searched for tutorials and examples on how to access the data store from the C# class but didn't find anything that helped in how to do it.

So please if you could indicate me a tutorial or something else that helps me learn this I'd be very grateful. Thank you in advance

PS- I'm starting with C# and Silverlight but know how to code in C and C++.

Comment: You should Give Any Code For Better Understand